# Create a frontpage.php and static page template

Tags: posts, pages, frontpage

I am a little confused.

**Reading settings :** 
1) Front page -> Home -> `Frontpage.php`
2) Posts page -> News -> `pages_news.php` [this is custom page template :Pages Custom news ]

From Pages:
3) Pages -> News -> Edit -> Template -> Pages Custom news

My `frontpage.php` works but my custom page template `pages_news.php` from news didn't work.
specifically, i customize the template with other settings or remove all and didn't work. It displays all the content. Also, I want to publish the first 6 posts (Without the sticky post) to `frontpage.php` and the others posts or articles to `pages_news.php`

Comment: from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page - *Do not use a custom Page template for this page! home.php or index.php will be used to generate this page.*

Comment: Which template do the stuff instead of your `pages_news`? Also check your template for heading: `<?php /* Template Name: News Page */`

Comment: @Michael my `frontpage.php` works For this page i don't use custom page template, but only for news. Max Yudin, what exactly you mean? The template name have checked correctly.

Comment: With some changes i realized that the **custom page template** gets the content from  `index.php`. why this happens;

Comment: What i am doing wrong? I spend many hours to find the solution. The curious is that the page news is not loaded from the custom page template but only from `index.php`.

Comment: have you actually reviewed the **full** linked Codex chapter http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page ?

Answer (score 1):

When you make a page the page for posts, it is no longer a *page* in the conventional sense, so it won't load your custom page template. See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) to learn how WordPress selects a template based on the requested page.

This behavior also extends to [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). `is_page()` will return `false` on the page selected as page for posts, while `is_home()` will return `true`.

Rename your `pages_news.php` to `home.php`, no need to select it as the template (as we have seen, it is ignored anyway).

Comment: First of all many thanks for the responses and the conversation that we have. I read the template Hierarchy. I think that this question have so many solutions. The first is that described by @Milo, the second is that i do: I disable **from reading settings the post page** as default. Then, create a **custom page template** with name : `pages_custom_news.php`. And works. I did the right thing; With this solution have i any problems? The 3rd thing that i want to question is **How can i publish only the first 6 posts to frontpage.php and the others posts to my custom page template?** Thanks again

Comment: I need two static pages. One for `home.php` and another one for `news.php` s. In the `home.php` i wll enable/publish only the first 6 posts and for `news.php` the remaining articles 7 and under.

Comment: **Comment or Answer my question?** I am not sure so i write a comment, but i want your feedback. After many efforts i do that: First i create a `frontpage.php`, then for **reading options** i enable **front page** and set as default the **post page**, also i create a **custom page template for news**. In `frontpage` posted the first 6 posts/articles and in `news` posted the remaining posts. So far I have no problem. I want to read your feedback. Thanks in advance.